# What is the voice in the sentence?

Tags: passive-voice

> You are not supposed to do this.

Is it active or passive voice?

Comment: Voting to reject migration.  This is just a question of English usage, without much context. It's not particularly about English Learning.

Comment: Note ot ELU mods:  ELL is not a dumping ground for question that are show no effort, or are not useful

Comment: It's active. "Supposed" is here a participial adjective that expresses medium deontic modality.